# Inno setup virus

Tags: c++, qt, inno-setup, virus

I created a setup for my application using Inno Setup. The probem is that when I try to execute the setup or send it via email, it's considered as a virus...

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{F6D8837D-F542-4326-A245-4B64AE8E8CD0}
AppName=S24
AppVersion=1.0
;AppVerName=S24 1.0
AppPublisher=Pierre Lagoutte
AppPublisherURL=https://s24.plagoutte.eu/
AppSupportURL=https://s24.plagoutte.eu/
AppUpdatesURL=https://s24.plagoutte.eu/
DefaultDirName={pf}\S24
DefaultGroupName=S24
AllowNoIcons=yes
LicenseFile=C:\Users\Pierre\Documents\Qt\build-S24-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2013_32bit-Release\release\licence.txt
OutputDir=C:\Users\Pierre\Documents\Qt\S24\setup\1.0
OutputBaseFilename=S24-Setup-22062018
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "brazilianportuguese"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\BrazilianPortuguese.isl"
Name: "catalan"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Catalan.isl"
Name: "corsican"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Corsican.isl"
Name: "czech"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Czech.isl"
Name: "danish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Danish.isl"
Name: "dutch"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Dutch.isl"
Name: "finnish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Finnish.isl"
Name: "french"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\French.isl"
Name: "german"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\German.isl"
Name: "greek"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Greek.isl"
Name: "hebrew"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Hebrew.isl"
Name: "hungarian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Hungarian.isl"
Name: "italian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Italian.isl"
Name: "japanese"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Japanese.isl"
Name: "norwegian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Norwegian.isl"
Name: "polish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Polish.isl"
Name: "portuguese"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Portuguese.isl"
Name: "russian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Russian.isl"
Name: "scottishgaelic"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\ScottishGaelic.isl"
Name: "serbiancyrillic"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\SerbianCyrillic.isl"
Name: "serbianlatin"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\SerbianLatin.isl"
Name: "slovenian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Slovenian.isl"
Name: "spanish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Spanish.isl"
Name: "turkish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Turkish.isl"
Name: "ukrainian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Ukrainian.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked
Name: "quicklaunchicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateQuickLaunchIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked; OnlyBelowVersion: 0,6.1

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\Pierre\Documents\Qt\build-S24-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2013_32bit-Release\release\S24.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Pierre\Documents\Qt\build-S24-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2013_32bit-Release\release\platforms\*"; DestDir: "{app}\platforms"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "C:\Users\Pierre\Documents\Qt\build-S24-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2013_32bit-Release\release\libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Pierre\Documents\Qt\build-S24-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2013_32bit-Release\release\libstdc++-6.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Pierre\Documents\Qt\build-S24-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2013_32bit-Release\release\libwinpthread-1.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Pierre\Documents\Qt\build-S24-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2013_32bit-Release\release\Qt5Core.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Pierre\Documents\Qt\build-S24-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2013_32bit-Release\release\Qt5Gui.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Pierre\Documents\Qt\build-S24-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2013_32bit-Release\release\Qt5Widgets.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\S24"; Filename: "{app}\S24.exe"
Name: "{group}\{cm:ProgramOnTheWeb,S24}"; Filename: "https://s24.plagoutte.eu/"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,S24}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\S24"; Filename: "{app}\S24.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\S24"; Filename: "{app}\S24.exe"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\S24.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,S24}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

My application is very simple, and my antivirus doesn't report me it's a virus when I launch it. It's really the setup and uninstall wizard of Inno Setup.

Comment: Probably nothing you can do but complain to your AV about the false positive. However that is unlikely to get it fixed.

Comment: Most mail services won't let you send any executable file at all (see gmail).

Comment: zip it and use a password (the av wont be able to open the archive then). if necessary, rename the zip to .jpg or something else

Comment: @DimChtz / MauriceRandomNumber I compressend my executable file into a RAR file. Also, I would like to distribute my application, so I can't set a password...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Running setup exe: it is unclear what you mean by "considered as a virus". I guess you are talking about the standard warning "this program may harm your computer". Well, it is shown for any program that requires administrative privileges to run (and all setup programs do). You have two options here: 1) find a setup program that can run in the user mode, or 2) buy a code-signing certificate. The second option will not remove the warning, but will make it pretty friendly.
2. Sending the exe as an email attachment. Forget it. That stopped working like ten years ago. Almost every mail server in the world block executable attachments. Upload your exe somewhere and send the link, not the exe itself.
3. Upload your exe to www.virustotal.com and check it. Antivirus programs do show false positives now and then. No big deal here, just contact the antivirus developer and explain the problem (and provide a link to the exe). They fix false positives quickly enough.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently investigating this. There are more things to consider here.
First. Inno setup is a widely used install-package maker, even for malware. Therefore antivirus software deal with any packages created on it very suspiciously.
Second. Most antivirus software is set to check online files for their "reputation". In my case I was creating an .exe package for download, so my antivirus checked its "reputation". Since after every compile it was always somehow new, it has been downloaded by too few users and therefore was given low reputation. In my case it was "Heur.AdvML.B" threat.

If none of the proposed answers by other users suit you. I'd ignore the message until the .exe package is complete and then send it to the database of the antivirus, that checks emails on the server, as a false positive.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, in my case, windows would directly delete the installer. I recommend you use other installer creators like installforge or anything else...